# Can we insert a document to a particular directory using PojoRepository in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am communicating MarkLogic database using Java API. I am creating a pojo and inserting the document using pojo repository instance.With Pojo repository I am able to set the Id.
For example my **pojo** class is **com.PersonalizedMAM.Pojo.AssetPojo**
when I am setting the **Id** like **/images/Akhil.jpg** after inserting **uri** looks like **com.PersonalizedMAM.Pojo.AssetPojo/%2Fimages%2FAkhil.jpg.json**
But I want my uri to look like **com.PersonalizedMAM.Pojo.AssetPojo/images/Akhil.jpg.json** or
**/images/com.PersonalizedMAM.Pojo.AssetPojo/Akhil.jpg.json** So that it will be easy for me to search through directory.
 Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the URI. The POJO interface is intended for a Java-first view of the data, with the database representation largely opaque. The conceptual unit of search is an object, for example, not a database document.

If you need control over the database representation, then you could create your own persistence scheme using [JacksonDataBindHandle](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/io/JacksonDatabindHandle.html) and [JSONDocumentManager](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/JSONDocumentManager.html), rather than [PojoRepository](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/pojo/PojoRepository.html).

If you say more about your use, e.g. why you need to "search through the directory", perhaps someone here can suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: I just want to group the docs in certain directory basing on some particular json properties so I thought search by directory is effecient while searching.I guess I can do the same with collections, I mean grouping the docs basing on collections

Comment: You can put a range index on the json properties themselves, and use those for grouping/faceting directly..

Comment: Collections are very efficient, and the recommended way to "group" documents, so, yes, that is a better choice than what you want to do with "directories". What you're thinking of as a directory really isn't. In a URI like /a/b/c.xml, "a" and "b" are just components of the URI, not a physical directory.